# how to change space between rows only for specific columns using bootstrap grid system?

Tags: html, css, grid, rows

I have two divs which repeat on every row, one of them is taller and so increases the height of each row, causing a large gap under the smaller div. here is what I mean:

http://prntscr.com/cf7cbh

This is my html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row col-lg-4">small div</div>
    <div class="row col-lg-2">small div</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">tall div</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to have the divs stack on top of each other with no gaps despite different sizes, I tried many things however nothing changes, hopefully someone can help, thanks!

Comment: have you try source code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Would fixed heights be an issue? and will it always be 2 small div's next to a big one?